# Qt: How to draw (and use) lineEdit inside delegate?

Tags: c++, qt, delegates, qpainter, qlineedit

I have a custom list, and on the view (with the `QStyledItemDelegate`) I want display many things, including a text edit
(think about an online shopping cart where you have the items (photos and infos of them) and next to them you can change the quantity, but within a text edit, and not a spinbox).

This text edit should be able to communicate with the model. Currently I can only draw an empty textEdit, but I don't know how to connect it properly to the `editorEvent` ( and `createEditor`, `setEditorData`).

```
void CustomDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                           const QStyleOptionViewItem &opt,
                           const QModelIndex &idx) const
{
      // My other painting stuff (labels, shapes...)
    QStyleOptionFrame panelFrame;
    QLineEdit lineEdit;
    panelFrame.initFrom(&lineEdit);
    panelFrame.rect = rectLE;
    panelFrame.state |= QStyle::State_Sunken;
    QApplication::style()->drawPrimitive(QStyle::PE_PanelLineEdit, &panelFrame, painter);
}

QWidget *CustomDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    auto editor = new QLineEdit(parent);
    editor->setText("test");
    return editor;
}


void CustomDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    auto lineEdit = dynamic_cast<QLineEdit*>(editor);
    if(lineEdit)
    {
        lineEdit->setText("test2");
    }
}
```

As a the result I can only see an empty `lineEdit` and can't really interact with it.

- If I would have multpiple `lineEdit`s inside one `modelIndex` delegate, how could I differentiate them in the `setEditorData` and `createEditor`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot several things in my implementation:

1. To "interact" with the `lineEdit` the `Qt::ItemIsEditable` flag must be set in the `QAbstractListModel::flags()`, otherwise the *Editor* functions in the Delegate won't get called.
2. To reimplement `updateEditorGeometry()` where you specify the `lineEdit`'s position.
3. To reimplement `setModelData()` where you can communicate with the model.
4. To draw the text in the Delegate's `paint()` function after `drawPrimitive` (*drawPrimitive* just draws the frame, but you want to draw the text you wrote in lineEdit as well. You can get it from the model)

Answer (score 0):

By default, editor in `QAbstractItemView` is created only by edit triggers, those are set to it. Refer to [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qabstractitemview.html#EditTrigger-enum)

To make a view interactive in sense of rendered rows as regular widgets you can use a workaround.

I've used this approach with `QListView` and `QStyledItemDelegate`.

When i faced with same problem, i've tracked a `viewport`'s mouse move event, to get a `QModelIndex` under the mouse cursor and if it was valid and different from previous value, i close an editor (if one was opened) and open a new one using methods `QAbstractItemView::closePersistentEditor` and `QAbstractItemView::openPersistentEditor`.

In my `QStyledItemDelegate` derived class i've overrided `createEditor`, `setEditorData` and `updateEditorGeometry` methods.

In `createEditor` just create a widget, in `updateEditorGeometry` setGeometry to editor, in `setEditorData` get required data to render from `QModelIndex` and set it to the editor widget.

The same widget class i've used to render all rows in view in `paint` method.